# A curve dividing a square in a given ratio

Tags: geometry

What does it mean for a curve to divide a square in a given ratio? Does it necessarily mean it has to intersect it at two points. Can it be that we have a circle of the given area inside it, thereby dividing it in the given ratio?

Comment: Depends on the [context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve). If closed curves are allowed, the circle would be fine.

Comment: @Jens In what context, must it mean that it has to intersect it at two points.

Comment: It would be easier if you could provide the context of your question. Is there any reason to think a closed curve is not allowed?

Comment: Presumably the area of the square is divided in the prescribed ratio (as opposed to the perimeter). The curve should unambiguously split the square in two regions. Whether these must be connected or simply connected is unsure. This must be stated.